# Finding the summation of a product of the particular binomial coefficients: $\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n-j}{p} \binom{m+j}{q}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation

How can I simplify the following expression?

> $$\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n-j}{p} \binom{m+j}{q}$$

where $n,m,p,q,k$ are positive constants 
such that $n-k \ge p$ and $m \ge q$.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what $k$ is, too :)

Comment: As it stands, you cannot simplify it to a single expression.

Comment: I assume that $k=n-p$.  In any case, try generating series.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the condition for k.

Comment: I tried to make few polynomial expansions to achieve the above form but all in vain.

Comment: If you take $k = n-p$ (i.e. maximal) then the expansion
$$(1-x)^{-p-1} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {p+j \choose p}x^j$$ (and a similar one for $q$) may help.

Comment: @WimC: If $n-k\le p$ and $m\le q$, then the sum is $\binom{n+m+1}{p+q+1}$, but that only applies to the question when $n-k=p$ and $m=q$.

Comment: @robjohn How you got that result if conditions are satisfied?

Comment: @Shashwat: I have added limited answer that covers that case.

Answer (score 2):

If $n-k=p$ and $m=q$, then we can use the identity
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-p-1}
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i\binom{-p-1}{i}x^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{p+i}{i}x^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{p+i}{p}x^i\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-p-1}(1-x)^{-q-1}
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{p+i}{p}x^i\;\;\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{q+j}{q}x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{p+i}{p}x^i\binom{q+j}{q}x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{n=j+p}^\infty\binom{n-j}{p}x^{n-j-p}\binom{q+j}{q}x^j\\
&=\sum_{n=p}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{n-p}\binom{n-j}{p}\binom{q+j}{q}x^{n-p}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Of course, from $(1)$ we get
$$
(1-x)^{-p-q-2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{p+q+1+k}{p+q+1}x^k\tag{3}
$$
Equating the terms with identical powers of $x$ and remembering that $n-k=p$ and $m=q$, we get
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-p}\binom{n-j}{p}\binom{m+j}{q}=\binom{n+m+1}{p+q+1}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think the general term for OP is unsolvable.

Comment: Can you please explain how the substitution $i=n-(j+p)$works in this case.I could not get how you reached this step.$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{n=j+p}^\infty\binom{n-j}{p}x^{n-j-p}\binom{q+j}{q}x^j$$and the following step in which you rearranged the summation again.

Answer (score 0):

Another hypergeometric expression from Maple:

$$ {n\choose p}{m\choose q}{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,m+1,-n+p;\,-n,m-q+1;\,1)}-
{n-1-k\choose p}{m+1+k\choose q}
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,m+2+k,-n+1+k+p;\,-n+k+1,m+k+2-q;\,1)}
$$